# How to find number of matches to regexp in perl6?

Tags: regex, raku

In Perl 5 we can write

```
my @things = $text =~ /thing/g;
```

And `$things` in scalar context is number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring `thing` in string `$text`.

How to do this in Perl 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
my $text = 'thingthingthing'
my @things = $text ~~ m:g/thing/;
say +@things; # 3
```

`~~` matches the left side against the right side, `m:g` makes the test return a `List[Match]` containing all the results.

Answer (score 5):

I found solution on `RosettaCode`.

> http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#Perl_6

```
say '01001011'.comb(/1/).elems;     #prints 4
```

Comment: Note that currently you can make this go a lot faster if the regular expression just consists of a string: `say '01001011'.comb("1").elems` (which is about 15x faster because it doesn't use the regular expression engine and the many, many `Match` object creations)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Changed the RosettaCode example to use a Str as the argument, with a note that it being basically the same as a regex.